# Filter JSON Array in python

Tags: arrays, json, python-3.x

Its me again.
I have a big one line JSON Array which I get as a response from a url.

It looks something like this:

```
[{"completed":"XXXXXXXXX","flow":"XXXXXX","process":"XXXXX","step":"XXXXXXX","thingname":"INEEDTHISFORLATER"},{"completed":"XXXXXXXXXX","flow":"XXXXXXXX","process":"XXXXXXX","step":"XXXXXXXX","thingname":"INEEDTHISFORLATER"}]
```

And I need to filter the lines like so that I only extract "INEEDTHISFORLATER" and save it to a new file.

I tried many things with pandas but it didnt work because its a one-liner aparrently.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: I strongly suggest you use the Python program to read the incoming JSON as JSON, and then in iterate over the JSON outputting one line at a time.

Comment: Does it have to be interpreted as JSON? I dont have that much knowledge with that so I thought I can maybe prevent using JSON interpretations and just treat it as a .txt file.

Comment: There is a package called `json` in native python. [see this](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`json`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html) packge to handle your case

```
import json

s = '[{"completed":"XXXXXXXXX","flow":"XXXXXX","process":"XXXXX","step":"XXXXXXX","thingname":"INEEDTHISFORLATER"},{"completed":"XXXXXXXXXX","flow":"XXXXXXXX","process":"XXXXXXX","step":"XXXXXXXX","thingname":"INEEDTHISFORLATER"}]'

obj = json.loads(s)

with open('file.txt', "w") as file:
    for item in obj:
        file.write(item['thingname'] + "\n")
```

`file.txt`:

```
INEEDTHISFORLATER
INEEDTHISFORLATER
```

Comment: Thanks for the nice explanation. Might use that but I just reworked my question if that makes the solution easier! If not, I will use your solution. Thank you!!

Comment: Updated according to your new question.

Comment: Perfect! Can I just define s as "file = open('TEMPFILE.json', "r")" ?

Comment: Updated again, I missed the output part in my answer

Comment: Thank you! If I let "s" open my tempfile.json which is a long one line json array I get this error: "The JSON object must be str not TextIOWrapper"

Comment: Isn't it **response from a url**, please confirm what you want to ask, you are changing your question back and forth.

Comment: If its a file you need to `with open(file, "r") as f:` and `s = f.read()`

Comment: I get the content of a URL, save it as a json array which is named tempfile.json. The file exactly contains the given example in my question.

Comment: I answered your question, then you changed the question, and I updated my answer, now you add more and more info to the question. I am happy to help but not endlessly, if you don't think this answer is helping then let it be.

Comment: It helped me perfectly fine! I didnt want to confuse you! Thanks for the help!